# Send back List with onBackPressed() after Serializable

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, bundle, serializable

How to update List values after onBackPressed() action in Activity B and save this changes in List in Activity A.

Activity A:

```
Intent order = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OrderActivity.class);
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putSerializable("order", (Serializable) orderPositions);
                    order.putExtra("order", args);
                    startActivity(order);
```

Activity B:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    menuActivity.setOrderPositions(orderPositions);
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}
```

I have also List setter (menuActivity.setOrderPositions(orderPositions);) in activity A but after that i have null List.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `startActivityForResult` in first activity and `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, <YOUR_LIST>)` in second activity before `finish()` call. In first activity get the data in `onActivityResult` method.

But I recommend use some storage (for example, database) to store your data and accept to it from any activity.

Or you can create some singleton and store your list in instance.

Answer (score 1):

call 
 "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); "
on onResume() method of the activity A 
Note: adapter is the adpater class we define for listview. it will refresh the list view . i use  it in my case and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I've made method that implicate count of duplicated positions and delete duplicated positions.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void checkForDuplicates(ArrayList<OrderSchema> orderPositions)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < orderPositions.size(); i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < orderPositions.size(); j++) 
        {
            if (Objects.equals(orderPositions.get(i).getPositionID(), orderPositions.get(j).getPositionID()) && (i != j))
            {
                Integer count = orderPositions.get(i).getCount();
                count += 1;
                orderPositions.get(i).setCount(count);

                orderPositions.remove(j);
                j = j -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```